# Выборка из строки отдельных значений в теге input

Tags: php, html, html5

Есть форма, в которой имеется пункт ФИО.
Как сделать выборку именно фамилии для дальнейшего использования в файле PHP.

Прошу прощения, если задаю глупые вопросы, но я ещё новичок :)
Заранее спасибо, за уделенное время

```
<!--Форма HTML-->
<form action="handler.php">
        <label>ФИО</label>
        <input type="text" name="fio">
    </form>
        

/*Файл handler.php*/
<label>Ваша фамилия:</label>
<?php 
     print();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам проще всего сделать 3 разных поля, в каждом из которых отдельно передавать фамилию, имя и отчество:

```html
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="middle_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Получение каждого параметра в `handler.php`:

```php
echo $_POST['last_name'] . '<br />';
echo $_POST['first_name'] . '<br />';
echo $_POST['middle_name'] . '<br />';
```

**Update.**

```php
$data = explode(' ', $_POST['name']);
echo reset($data);
```

Comment: Я так до этого и делал, но требуется именно в одно поле вместить

Comment: @ShahrierTurdiev, тогда вы можете разбить строку по пробелу и взять первый элемент массива, если у вас подразумевается пробел после каждого слова. Также обновил свой ответ.

Comment: @HakuKimura `ИвановИван Иванович` и Ваш пример придет в негодность в силу недоработки..покажите хоть на примере "новичку" (ему) как этого избежать

Comment: @CryEngineV-FlowGraph, какая формулировка вопроса — такой и ответ. Правильный вариант передачи данных, чтобы избежать таких ситуаций, я автору также написал.